# Pivot table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Please help me out in SQL server PIVOT Table. I got the output like below. Now I want the total count of allocation pending and coding pending in separate columns under each date row.

```
select ScanDate, filestatus, COUNT(filestatus) as filecount from ScanLog 
where FileSource = 'ebridge'
group by filestatus, ScanDate

scandate        filestatus      filecount
2013-08-01  Allocation Pending  8
2013-08-01  Coding Pending      1
2013-08-02  Allocation Pending  4
2013-08-02  Coding Pending      1
2013-08-03  Allocation Pending  4
2013-08-04  Allocation Pending  18
2013-08-04  Coding Pending      3
2013-08-05  Allocation Pending  6
```

I used the following code but got error as 'scandate' is not a valid field. Please guide me.

```
select [scandate] from ScanLog 
pivot (count(scandate) 
for filestatus in ([allocation pending],[coding pending])) as A
where FileSource = 'ebridge'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
      ScanDate DATETIME
    , FileSource VARCHAR(10)    
    , FileStatus VARCHAR(30)
    , FileCount INT

)

INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES 
    ('2013-08-01', 'ebridge', 'Allocation Pending', 8),
    ('2013-08-01', 'ebridge', 'Coding Pending', 1),
    ('2013-08-02', 'ebridge', 'Allocation Pending', 4),
    ('2013-08-02', 'ebridge', 'Coding Pending', 1),
    ('2013-08-03', 'ebridge', 'Allocation Pending', 4),
    ('2013-08-04', 'ebridge', 'Allocation Pending', 18),
    ('2013-08-04', 'ebridge', 'Coding Pending', 3),
    ('2013-08-05', 'ebridge', 'Allocation Pending', 6)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT scandate, filestatus
    FROM @temp
    WHERE FileSource = 'ebridge'
) t
PIVOT (
    COUNT(scandate)
    FOR filestatus IN ([Allocation Pending], [Coding Pending])
) a
```

Comment: You are missing the `where FileSource = 'ebridge'`

Comment: @Devart Thank you very much for your solution. Its works fine. Just I changed Pivot(Count(Filestatus) instead of count(scandate).

Comment: If this solution fully suit you, please approve it.

Answer (score 2):

try this query,
`you may use left outer , right outer join or inner join` depends on how the data is in your table

```
SELECT  frst.scandate
    ,   frst.filestatus
    ,   frst.filecount
    ,   secnd.filestatus
    ,   secnd.filecount1
FROM
(
    SELECT  scandate
        ,   filestatus
        ,   COUNT(filestatus) AS filecount
    FROM ScanLog 
    WHERE FileSource = 'ebridge'
        AND filestatus = 'Allocation Pending'
    GROUP BY
        filestatus
    ,   scandate
) frst
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT  scandate
        ,   filestatus
        ,   COUNT(filestatus) AS filecount1
    FROM ScanLog 
    WHERE FileSource = 'ebridge'
        AND filestatus = 'Coding Pending'
    GROUP BY
        filestatus
    ,   scandate
) secnd ON frst.scandate = secnd.scandate
```